# How to validate a web adress in ruby

Tags: ruby

Most of solution use URI.regexp. However, it requires to put a protocol prefix to be valid.

I want to make sure that both these are valid:

- http://www.foo.bar
- www.foo.bar

And URI.regexp won't match www.foo.bar

Any recommendations how to do this?

Comment: You check see if the URL starts with an http(s)? and if it doesn't add http:// to be beginning of it. Then use the URI.regexp function.

Comment: Yeah. It could work. However, I don't want to make immediately this assumption, because it was https:// than entering www.foo.bar will figure it out. However, after I add http:// it will just fail

Comment: If you're not wedded to Ruby, [URI::Find::Schemeless](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Find::Schemeless) can do it in Perl.  I assume you want to be able to find schemeless URLs in a string like `"This is a string that has www.example.com in it"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? Check if it's a valid domain with a valid extension? Like foo.notexisting vs. foo.com?

Comment: @daremkd Validate = make sure that string is correct. As example "http://foo.bar.com" and "foo.bar.com" are valid, but "foo#" is not.